# Add two values-input string was not in a correct format

Tags: c#, string, int

I read data from data reader and want to add some value to that.It give me  error

> *input string was not in a correct format*

here is my code

```
int OldAmount = 0;
while (dr.Read())
{
   OldAmount = dr.GetInt32(0);
}
string CurrentAmount = (Convert.ToInt32(amnt) + Convert.ToInt32(OldAmount)).ToString();
```

Where `amnt` is `string` and has `23000` value.

Is there anything wrong?

Comment: That's not an int.  Ints don't have decimal places.

Comment: `oldAmount` already is of type `int`.

Comment: @Rawling Are you sure this is good duplicate? Because duplicate parse `string` to `double` but this question parse `string` to `int` :\

Comment: @SonerGönül Good point, I read this as "group separator being treated as decimal separator" but it may well be "trying to parse a floating point value as an int"...

Comment: @Rawling Yeah, that was confused me as well :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`Convert.ToInt32` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.convert.toint32%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) uses your current culture settings.

Looks like your [`CurrentCulture`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.currentculture%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)'s [`NumberDecimalSeparator` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.numberformatinfo.numberdecimalseparator.aspx) is not `.` or/and since `Convert.ToInt32` uses [`NumberStyles.Integer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.numberstyles.aspx) by default, you need [`NumberStyles.AllowDecimalPoint`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.numberstyles.aspx) also to point your decimal separator.

You can use [`Int32.Parse(String, NumberStyles, IFormatProvider)` overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9yaffedz%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) instead to provide like;

```
int amnt = Int32.Parse("23000.00",
                       NumberStyles.Integer | NumberStyles.AllowDecimalPoint, 
                       CultureInfo.InvariantCulture); //23000
```

Then you can use this value like;

```
string CurrentAmount = (amnt + OldAmount).ToString();
```

By the way, since your string doesn't have any trailing or leading white space or leading sign, using `NumberStyles.Integer` is unnecessary in your case. You can just do;

```
int amnt = Int32.Parse("23000.00",
                       NumberStyles.AllowDecimalPoint, 
                       CultureInfo.InvariantCulture); //23000
```

Answer (score 0):

`Convert.ToInt` depends on your computer `CurrentCulture`.
If your decimal separator other that `.` you can get that exception.

You can use [Int.Parse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int32.parse%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) with specification of string format, like `Int32.Parse("23000.00", NumberStyles.AllowDecimalPoint);`.

But are you sure it should be `int` not `decimal`?

Answer (score 0):

You are converting to int, while you have decimal.
Change `convert.ToInt32(amnt)` to `convert.ToDecimal(amnt)`

Answer (score 0):

`OldAmount` is already an int, you don't need to convert it again.  Try:

```
string CurrentAmount = (int.Parse("23000.00", NumberStyles.AllowDecimalPoint) + OldAmount).ToString();
```

or just use a decimal instead.